# angular.js select filter type of input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular.js for quite short time, and sometimes i have a feeling, that I know nothing about html and javascript because of angular's odds when hitting things that in my imagination should, and probably ARE very simple.

Here is my headache:

my currents controller scope.persons is a list of... persons aquired by factory from backend.
it shows nicely with ng-repeat, and filters with input:

```
<input ng-model='query.firstname'> // search by firstname
<input ng-model='query.lastname'> // search by lastname

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='person in persons | filter: query'> firstname: {{person.firstname}}, lastname: {{person.lastname}}
</ul>
```

but i want to make it possible to choose from  what should be filter.

something like:

```
<select> 
    <option value='query.firstname'> by firstname </option>
    <option value='query.lastname'> by lastname </option>
```

I tried to mess around in a lot of ways, which Im embarassed to show :), but im lost how to connect select with input ng-model...

thanks for help, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this approach. HTML:

```
<select ng-model="filter">
    <option value='firstname'>by firstname </option>
    <option value='lastname'>by lastname </option>
</select>

<input ng-model='query'>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='person in persons | filter: getFilter()'> firstname: {{person.firstname}}, lastname: {{person.lastname}}
</ul>
```

and in controller construct filter expression dynamically:

```
$scope.getFilter = function() {
    var filter = {};
    filter[$scope.filter] = $scope.query;
    return filter;
};
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/W5dIMYp3C8p3Yid9iglE?p=preview

Comment: This is almost perfect except one thing what if you want to look inside more than one key in your json object... Say you have an all option as well. This feels magical to me. What am I missing?